# Error with SDL window?

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, glew

In my code, I had these things that would check if my code had errors in creating a SDL window, initializing GLEW, whatever.  They would go off and my program would still work and in [the guide I'm following](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8t3m2mRH7qs), no errors went off what so ever.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Also, the `glClearColor()` doesn't seem to work.  I think its related to the errors above.

My code:

```
// g++ `pkg-config --cflags glew sdl2` main.cpp `pkg-config --libs glew sdl2`
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

enum class GameState { PLAY, EXIT };

class MainGame
{
public:
    MainGame();
    ~MainGame();

    void run();

private:
    void initSystems();
    void gameLoop();
    void processInput();
    void drawGame();

    SDL_Window* _window;
    int _screenWidth;
    int _screenHeight;

    int _errorCount;

    GameState _gameState;
};

//Function To Display A Error Message When Something Doesnt Work As Inteded/Properly.
void fatalError(std::string errorMsg)
{
    std::cout << errorMsg << std::endl;
}

//When Called, Inits Most Of The Important Vars, Sets Game State And Does An Error Check
MainGame::MainGame()
{
    _errorCount = 0;
    _window = nullptr;
    _screenWidth = 1024;
    _screenHeight = 768;
    _gameState = GameState::PLAY;

    if (_window == nullptr) {
        fatalError("SDL Window Could Not Be Created.");
        _errorCount += 1;
    }

    SDL_GLContext glContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(_window);

    if (glContext == nullptr) {
        fatalError("SDL_GL Context Could Not Be Created.");
        _errorCount += 1;
    }

    GLenum error = glewInit();

    if (error != GLEW_OK) {
        fatalError("Could Not Initialize Glew.");
        _errorCount += 1;
    }

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);

    glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
}

MainGame::~MainGame()
{
}

void MainGame::run()
{
    initSystems();
    gameLoop();
}

// Initializes The SDL Window.
void MainGame::initSystems()
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    _window = SDL_CreateWindow("Game Engine", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, _screenWidth, _screenHeight, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
}

void MainGame::gameLoop()
{
    while (_gameState != GameState::EXIT) {
        processInput();
        drawGame();
    }
}

void MainGame::processInput()
{
    SDL_Event evnt;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&evnt) == true) {
        switch (evnt.type) {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            _gameState = GameState::EXIT;
            break;
        case  SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
            std::cout << evnt.motion.x << ", " << evnt.motion.y << "\n";
            break;
        }
    }
}

void MainGame::drawGame()
{
    glClearDepth(1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(_window);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    MainGame mainGame;
    mainGame.run();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, and your code is hard to reach (should be in the question itself) - I suppose that reduces your chances to get help a lot. Please read "how to ask" section or/and look at other questions as the reference. Even so, one glance at your code is enough to say it is wrong - you check for window in constructor, but create it in other method - which clearly happens after constructor. Also setting GL attributes after creating context have no effect on already created contexts.

Answer (score 2):

- Don't call `SDL_GL_CreateContext()` with a NULL pointer.
- Don't call `SDL_GL_SetAttribute()` *after* you create a window, won't do anything useful.
- Clean up your window & GL context in your destructor.
- Set the clear color each time through the draw function for sanity.
- You can clear the color and depth planes in a single call.
- "Fatal" errors should usually kill the program ASAP.  Here I used `exit()` but a `throw` would work too.

All together:

```
// g++ `pkg-config --cflags sdl2` main.cpp `pkg-config --libs glew sdl2`
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib> 

enum class GameState { PLAY, EXIT };

class MainGame
{
public:
    MainGame();
    ~MainGame();

    void run();

private:
    void processInput();
    void drawGame();

    SDL_Window* _window;
    SDL_GLContext _context;
    int _screenWidth;
    int _screenHeight;

    int _errorCount;

    GameState _gameState;
};

//Function To Display A Error Message When Something Doesnt Work As Inteded/Properly.
void fatalError(std::string errorMsg)
{
    std::cout << errorMsg << std::endl;
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

//When Called, Inits Most Of The Important Vars, Sets Game State And Does An Error Check
MainGame::MainGame()
{
    _errorCount = 0;
    _window = nullptr;
    _screenWidth = 1024;
    _screenHeight = 768;
    _gameState = GameState::PLAY;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
   _window = SDL_CreateWindow("Game Engine", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, _screenWidth, _screenHeight, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    if (_window == nullptr)
    {
        fatalError("SDL Window Could Not Be Created.");
        _errorCount += 1;
    }

    _context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(_window);
    if (_context == nullptr)
    {
        fatalError("SDL_GL Context Could Not Be Created.");
        _errorCount += 1;
    }

    GLenum error = glewInit();
    if (error != GLEW_OK)
    {
        fatalError("Could Not Initialize Glew.");
        _errorCount += 1;
    }
}

MainGame::~MainGame()
{
    SDL_GL_DeleteContext( _context );
    SDL_DestroyWindow( _window );
}

void MainGame::run()
{
    while (_gameState != GameState::EXIT)
    {
        processInput();
        drawGame();
    }
}

void MainGame::processInput()
{
    SDL_Event evnt;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&evnt) == true)
    {
        switch (evnt.type)
        {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            _gameState = GameState::EXIT;
            break;
        case  SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
            std::cout << evnt.motion.x << ", " << evnt.motion.y << "\n";
            break;
        }
    }
}

void MainGame::drawGame()
{
    glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClearDepth(1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(_window);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    MainGame mainGame;
    mainGame.run();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```